# When I push the next button in my react app song couldn't change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio

I am trying to change the music in my app when I click the next button. The name is changing correctly but the song isn't. I am using contextAPI. I tried to change index number and the name change but song couldn't change.

```
import { createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from 'react'
import dream from '../musics/dream.mp3';
import meta  from '../musics/meta.mp3';

export const  MainContext = createContext();

const Provider = ({children}) => {
    const [control, setControl] = useState(false)
    const [idx, setIdx] = useState(1)
    const musics = [dream,meta];
    const musicsName = ["Dream","Metamorphosis"]
    const [name, setName] = useState("Dream")
    const [music, setMusic] = useState(dream);
    const controlMusic = () => {
        const targetAudio = document.querySelector("#audioBtn");
        if (!control) {
            targetAudio.play();
            setControl(!control)
        }
        else {
            targetAudio.pause();
            setControl(!control)
        }
    }
    const nextMusic = () => {
        if (idx < musics.length)
        setIdx(idx + 1);
        setName(musicsName[idx]);
        setMusic(musics[idx]);
    }
    const data = {
        control,
        controlMusic,
        nextMusic,
        music,
        name,
    }

    return (
        <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
            {children}
        </MainContext.Provider>
        
    )
}

export default Provider;
```

Comment: It's because you're introducing native DOM queries to a library that uses its own system for reconciling DOM changes and they're conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

if name is changing that the source of the song is not right?
so maybe you are not passing the wright props